# Can I self submit back to a textarea box?

Tags: php, html

I am able to create a textarea box that will accept text and store that text to the $_POST super global, but I can't get the text to "come back" to the box once I submit it.  (The form is self submitting).  If I run a simple echo on the submitted data, however, it displays fine (as shown toward the end of the script below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <body> <?php require("Connection_to_WS.php");
echo ("<form action='Edit_Thread_Description.php' method='post'>");

IF (ISSET($_POST['revised_thread_descr'])) {
$revised_thread_descr=($_POST['revised_thread_descr']);
ECHO "Edit the Revised_Thread_Description here: <br> <textarea name='revised_thread_descr' rows='5' cols='50' value= $_POST[revised_thread_descr]";      // Fails to return any text on Submit.
?><p></textarea></p><br><?php
}
ELSE {$revised_thread_descr= '[some default]';
ECHO "Edit the Revised_Thread_Description here: <br> <textarea name= 'revised_thread_descr' rows='5' cols='50' value= $revised_thread_descr";
?><p></textarea></p><br><?php
}
ECHO '<br>';
echo $_POST['revised_thread_descr'];  // Succeeds in returning POST text from the textarea box upon Submit (but outside of the textarea box).
ECHO '<br>';
echo "Click 'Submit': <input type='Submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>";
echo '<br>';
mysqli_close($connection); 
?>
</body> </html>
```

Doing the same sort of thing was a breeze using "`<input type`", but I've sunk hours into getting `<textarea` to cooperate.  I   I'd be grateful for any assistance.

Comment: <textarea> <?php //the post stuff ?> </textarea> Textarea does not use Value to display the content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ann Sophie said, there is no "value" property on the textarea element 
(https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

if you want to dynamically append content to it, you can use :

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['revised_thread_descr'])): ?>
 <textarea><?= $_POST['revised_thread_descr'] ?></textarea>
<?php else: ?>
  //
```

Note that you have to echo it, in my example I used alternative syntax, 
(http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)
which I think is much more cleaner when you works with PHP + HTML

`<?= XXX ?>` is short for `<?php echo XXX; ?>`

Comment: Thanks for the responses; they helped nudge me along.  Here's my attempt to follow your suggestion:  IF(ISSET($_POST['revised_thread_descr'])):
$revised_thread_descr=($_POST['revised_thread_descr']); ?>
<p> Revised_thread_descr - EDIT HERE:</p><p><textarea name= 'revised_thread_descr' rows='5' cols='50' 
</textarea></p><br>
<?php       But it still doesn't get the box to repopulate with the submitted POST.     I'll try to 'answer my question' to add a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I botched a response via 'comment', above.  This continues that comment:

This code works, but won't repopulate the box with remarks submitted back to the script via the POST super global.

```
IF(ISSET($_POST['revised_thread_descr'])):
$revised_thread_descr=($_POST['revised_thread_descr']); ?>
<p> Revised_thread_descr - Edit here:</p><textarea   
name='revised_thread_descr' rows='5' cols='50' 
<p></textarea></p><br>
<?php 

ELSE:
    $revised_thread_descr= '[some default]'; ?>
<p> Revised_thread_descr - Edit here:</p><textarea name=      'revised_thread_descr' rows='5' cols='50' 
<p></textarea></p><br>
<?php
    ENDIF;

echo "Click 'Submit': <input type='Submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>";
echo '<br>';
mysqli_close($connection); 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This code, with just a slightly different placement of the `<p>` tags, gobbles up and displays all html material that comes after the closing `</textarea>` tag.

```
IF(ISSET($_POST['revised_thread_descr'])):
$revised_thread_descr=($_POST['revised_thread_descr']); ?>
<p> Revised_thread_descr - EDIT HERE:</p><p><textarea name=     'revised_thread_descr' rows='5' cols='50' 
</textarea></p><br>
<?php
```

As in the screenshot of the browser rendering, below.
[image: screenshot of browser rendering of script above]

Thanks, btw, for getting me to try that alternate syntax!  Less confusing.

Comment: You didn't close your textarea opening tag, it should be 
`<textarea name="x" rows="y" cols="z" > TEXT </textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

Bless you!  I'd given up and was going for a workaround.  I put in that tag caret as you suggested and it all worked.  Here is the gist of it, with everything working, and the textarea box populating correctly.  Thank you so much for your patience and persistence.  Tell me it gets easier... .

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <body> 
<?php
echo ("<form action='Textarea_Example.php' method='post'>");

// The first IF only executes after the script has run once and created a POST value.  On the second run, the first IF executes and successfully populates the textarea box with the latest POSTed value 
IF (ISSET($_POST['revised_thread_descr'])): ?>
<p>Edit current thread description:<p>
<textarea name= 'revised_thread_descr' rows='5' cols='50'> 
<?php echo $_POST['revised_thread_descr'] ?>
</textarea> 

<?php ELSE: 
$revised_thread_descr = 'some default'; ?>
<p>Edit current thread description:<p>
<p><textarea name= 'revised_thread_descr' rows='5' cols='50'> 
The textarea box opens with this in it, but only on the first run.  Then it successfully switches to the value typed to the textarea box and saved to POST
</textarea> 
<?php ENDIF; ?>
</p>
<?php
// here's the submit button
echo "Click 'Submit': <input type='Submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>";
?>
</body> </html>
```